# How to split a Pandas column of different lists into multiple columns and set it as column names?

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe

I have the following Pandas Dataframe.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "client": ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seventh", "eighth", "ninth", "tenth", "eleventh"],
    "Lifetime": [24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24],
    "Tokens": [30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
    "path": ["kyc", "co", "5dimes", "la", "la", "ku", "pv", "ipv", "lv", "7d", "222"],
    "requiredFields": [
        ['address', 'city', 'country', 'dobDay', 'dobMonth', 'dobYear', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'ssn', 'state', 'zip'],
        ['address', 'country', 'dobDay', 'dobMonth', 'dobYear', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'ssn', 'state', 'zip'],
        ['address', 'country', 'dobDay', 'dobMonth', 'dobYear', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'state', 'zip'],
        ['city', 'country', 'dobDay', 'dobMonth', 'dobYear', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'ssn', 'state', 'zip'],
        ['city', 'country', 'dobDay', 'dobMonth', 'dobYear', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'ssn', 'zip'],
        ['city', 'country', 'dobDay', 'dobMonth', 'dobYear', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'ssn'],
        ['city', 'country', 'dobDay', 'dobMonth', 'dobYear', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'state', 'zip'],
        ['country', 'dobDay', 'dobMonth', 'dobYear', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'ssn', 'state', 'zip'],
        ['country', 'dobDay', 'dobMonth', 'dobYear', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'ssn', 'zip'],
        ['country', 'dobDay', 'dobMonth', 'dobYear', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'state', 'zip'],
        ['dobDay', 'dobMonth', 'dobYear', 'firstName', 'lastName']
    ],
    "userIdRequired": [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True],
}
```

)
What I want to do is to make each item in the list go to a separate column. The result is a list item as a column name and its value "y". Something like this.

| client | Lifetime | Tokens | path | requiredFields | userIdRequired | address | city | country | dobDay | dobMonth | dobYear | firstName | lastName | ssn | state | zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| first | 24 | 30 | kyc | [address, city, country, dobDay, dobMonth, dobYear, firstName, lastName, ssn, state, zip] | True | y | y | y | y | y | y | y | y | y | y | y |
| second | 24 | 30 | co | [address, city, country, dobDay, dobMonth, dobYear, firstName, lastName, ssn, state, zip] | True | y | None | y | y | y | y | y | y | y | y | y |
| third | 24 | 30 | 5dimes | [address, city, country, dobDay, dobMonth, dobYear, firstName, lastName, state, zip] | True | y |  | y | y | y | y | y | y | y | y | y |
| fourth | 24 | 30 | la | [city, country, dobDay, dobMonth, dobYear, firstName, lastName, ssn, state, zip] | True | None | y | y | y | y | y | y | y | y | y | y |
| fifth | 24 | 30 | la | [city, country, dobDay, dobMonth, dobYear, firstName, lastName, ssn, zip] | True | None | y | y | y | y | y | y | y | y | None | y |
| sixth | 24 | 30 | ku | [city, country, dobDay, dobMonth, dobYear, firstName, lastName, ssn] | True | None | y | y | y | y | y | y | y | y | None | None |
| seventh | 24 | 30 | pv | [city, country, dobDay, dobMonth, dobYear, firstName, lastName, state, zip] | True | None | y | y | y | y | y | y | y | None | y | y |
| eighth | 24 | 30 | ipv | [country, dobDay, dobMonth, dobYear, firstName, lastName, ssn, state, zip] | True | None | None | y | y | y | y | y | y | y | y | y |
| ninth | 24 | 30 | lv | [country, dobDay, dobMonth, dobYear, firstName, lastName, ssn, zip] | True | None | None | y | y | y | y | y | y | y | None | y |
| tenth | 24 | 30 | 7d | [country, dobDay, dobMonth, dobYear, firstName, lastName, state, zip] | True | None | None | y | y | y | y | y | y | None | y | y |
| eleventh | 24 | 30 | 222 | [dobDay, dobMonth, dobYear, firstName, lastName] | True | None | None | None | y | y | y | y | y | None | None | None |

I can't use `apply` `pandas series` or `explode` or something similar, because then I will have different value order by columns. I also tried to use but with this solution [Pandas split a column of unequal length lists into multiple boolean columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64076919/pandas-split-a-column-of-unequal-length-lists-into-multiple-boolean-columns), but it generates duplicated columns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas convert a column of list to dummies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034928/pandas-convert-a-column-of-list-to-dummies)

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh no, it is something I also tried and it does not generate what I expect. This solution gives me all list elements in the row as column names and with this, it generates as many columns as many different lists I will have.

Comment: [RESOLVED]: required_fields_s = data['requiredFields'].explode()
    data = data.join(pd.crosstab(required_fields_s.index,required_fields_s).replace({0: None, 1: 'y'}))

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```py
out = data.join(data['requiredFields'].str[0].str.get_dummies(sep=', ').replace({0: None, 1: 'y'}))
```

```
print(out)

   client  Lifetime  Tokens    path  \
0   first        24      30     kyc
1  second        24      30      co
2   third        24      30  5dimes
3  fourth        24      30      la

                                          requiredFields  userIdRequired  \
0        [country, dobDay, dobMonth, dobYear, firstName]            True
1          [address, country, dobDay, dobMonth, dobYear]            True
2  [city, country, dobDay, dobMonth, dobYear, firstName]            True
3       [dobDay, dobMonth, dobYear, firstName, lastName]            True

  address  city country dobDay dobMonth dobYear firstName lastName
0    None  None       y      y        y       y         y     None
1       y  None       y      y        y       y      None     None
2    None     y       y      y        y       y         y     None
3    None  None    None      y        y       y         y        y
```

Comment: This solution does work for the data presented in the example, thank you. But it turns out, that the example data given here has differences from the original I am working with, and when I applied your solution to my original data it gave me problems - it does not show all the columns. I apologize, but I've already edited the example, I hope you can see if you can find a solution.